# Why isn't my Cocoa app visible while debugging?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm an experienced iOS developer trying to develop my first Cocoa app for OSX.

When the app hits my breakpoints, the app window is no longer visible. Why not? I see the app icon in the dock, but it doesn't become visible when I click on it.

Is there a way to change this or a workaround? I'd like to see the state of my app as I debug. I'm guessing I'm not the only one.

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 6.

Comment: Perhaps because the event loop is not running, since blocked by your debugging.

Comment: Did you perhaps set Hides On Deactivate on your window?

Comment: if the app is paused by debugger, it won't be able to render the view

Comment: You will still be able to see the window in its last rendered state (assuming it has been drawn on screen prior to the breakpoint) if you move other windows off of it.

Comment: Hide on Deactivate is not set. I'd love to see the window in it's last rendered state, but I don't see the window AT ALL.

Comment: It won't become key if you click on the icon but if you cycle through windows in mission control it should still be there beachballing. Unless something else is horribly wrong.

Comment: Well, I never thought about Mission Control. My window is there. I guess I would have expected it to do the same if I cmd-tab or clicked on the app icon in the dock. Thanks Vervious.